# Tailwind Applying Md Breakpoints at 375pixel Screen Width

Tags: css, tailwind-css, breakpoints

Tailwind is incorrectly applying styles. On a mobile device the height of the div should be using the default of h-4/5. However, on a screen width of 375p the md:h-3/5 is being picked up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Determined that there was an issue with my meta tag

Solution:

```
meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
```

The previous line read:

```
meta(name="viewp**OINT**", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
```

Just had to modify viewpoint to viewport.